# Number Theory and Self-Written Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-set-theory, integers

Given a natural number $N = a_{n}a_{n-1}\ldots a_{1}$ and its digits' multiset $D_{N} = \{a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n}\}$, we shall call it a *self-written* number if, and only if, it exists multisets $B = \{b_{1},b_{2},\ldots,b_{k}\}\subseteq D_{N}$ and $E = \{e_{1},e_{2},\ldots,e_{j}\}\subseteq D_{N}$ such that $B\cap E = \varnothing$ which satisfy the next condition:
$$N = b^{e}\quad\text{where}\quad b = b_{k}b_{k-1}\ldots b_{1}\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\, e = e_{j}e_{j-1}\ldots e_{1}$$
Once the definition has been made clear, we may now expose some examples. For instance, $121$ is self-written since $121 = 11^2$. The same happens to $1331$ once it can be rewritten as $1331 = 11^3$. Moreover, so it does to $14641$ given that $14641 = 11^4$. Thence it comes my first question: is there infinitely many self-written numbers? Secondly, is there any criteria to identify them quickly?

I think this is it. Thank you in advance for any contribution.

Comment: I am sure there are infinitely many.  One approach to find them is to write a large number with roughly equal numbers of each digit except $2$ and square it, hoping to have enough digits to cover your needs.  Naively (assuming the digits of the square are random) taking a nine digit number and squaring should work about $1/6$ of the time, but I did a few more than $6$ and didn't find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a neat trick for squaring numbers that end in $5$. Suppose we have a number $n = 10k+5$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then it's not too difficult to show that $n^2 = 100(k)(k+1)+25.$

For example, for $25^2$, just take the non-five part $2$, multiply by the next natural number $3$ to obtain $6$, and slap that in front of $25$ to obtain $25^2 = 625$.

With that said, I think considering $N$ of the form $N = (100\dots 005)^2$ might do the trick.

Comment: May I ask why the unaccept?